# Missing parameters on detectIntent() call

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to trigger a detectIntent in order to programmatically start a conversation with the user, but I'm having issues sending parameters. This is a snippet of code that I am using to debug the issue

https://gist.github.com/ftassi/aa602a6c6f3c881865c4dd2a534ad7ef

The detectIntent call seems to be fine. The intent gets identified from the event. 
I am just not able to send dialogFlow parameters in the correct way.

I know that dialogFlow think that some parameter is missing because I get a response with 
allRequiredParamsPresent: false,
and fulfillmentText filled with the next question to get the date.

What am I missing?

Anyway, is it correct to use detectIntent() to start a conversation with the user? I need to use the bot as a 
reminder (every morning every user need to be reached by the bot), but I also want to take advantage of contexts
in *that* conversation, so if the user answer the bot the conversation can follow its natural flow.

Is there a better option to do what I am trying to do ?